# How to dump HTTP body and headers sent with HTTP component with Apache Camel

Tags: java, groovy, apache-camel

How to dump HTTP body and headers sent with Apache Camel HTTP component using this route:

```
   from('direct:abc').
   setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, constant("${config.gnutch.solr.coreUrl}/select")).
   setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, constant("q=${q}&wt=xml")).
   setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant('application/xml')).
   setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant('GET')).
   setBody(constant(null)).
   to("http://null")
```

This is Camel DSL code in groovy. Is that possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
from("direct:abc")
 .to("http://domain.com/")
 .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
```

Also the [HTTP Component Documentation](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) suggests that you can extract the `HttpServletRequest` from the exchange like,

```
HttpServletRequest request = exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletRequest.class);
```

You can then alternatively do,

```
from("direct:abc").to("http://domain.com").process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletRequest.class);
        // Log request parameters
    }
});
```

Comment: First solution does not print request body. Second solution seems gives that ability, however this should not be processor, but type converter. I'll fix your reply and accept it.

Comment: How to read HttpServletResponse headers and body in above case because HttpServletResponse class does not have have getInputStream() method.

Answer (score 9):

This will help , use this in log message :

${headers}

Or

${in.headers}

This will print any incoming headers .

Checkout here : http://camel.apache.org/simple.html

Example :

Answer (score 4):

Try logging headers and content using one of HttpClient loggers.

Is is described in [Logging Practices](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/logging.html) (version 3.x in this case).

I am using loggers with names:

- httpclient.wire
- org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection

which gives me output like:

```
o.a.c.httpclient.HttpConnection - Open connection to 0.0.0.0:12454
httpclient.wire.header - >> "POST /some/path HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - >> "breadcrumbId: ID-localhost-55077[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - >> "path: http://0.0.0.0:65432/some/other/path[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - >> "User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - >> "Host: 0.0.0.0:12454[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - >> "Content-Length: 117[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - >> "[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.content - >> "{"a":"afeaafe","b":{"c":"53413"},"d":{"e":"vsegefawawewr"}}"
httpclient.wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - << "Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2016 07:24:24 GMT[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - << "Content-Type: application/octet-stream[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - << "Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2016 07:24:24 GMT[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - << "Content-Length: 7[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - << "Server: Jetty(9.2.10.v20150310)[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - << "[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.content - << "Success"
o.a.c.httpclient.HttpConnection - Releasing connection back to connection manager.
```

Answer (score 2):

With Camel 3.11 and apache httpclient 4.5 in Spring Boot 2.4 it required putting

```
logging.level.org.apache.http.wire=DEBUG
```

into the application.properties for me.