# Making a POST request using Camel

Tags: java, post, apache-camel

I have a camel route configured for reading from a JMS queue and POST it to a service. 
My route is :

```
from("jms:queue")
.marshal()
.json(JsonLibrary.GSON)
.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,constant("application/json"))
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
.process(new Processor1())
.to("https4:xxxxxx?throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
.process(new MyProcessor())
```

My Configuration :

```
HttpComponent httpc = getContext().getComponent("http4",HttpComponent.class);
httpc.setHttpConfiguaration(customHttpConfig())
```

and in customHttpConfig i set my auth details.

I am getting a 400 error from the server. But i am able to hit the server from Postman api and get successfull response.

In my Processor1 class ( before making the request), i am able to print the body of the message, which contains a json representation of my object.

But in the processor after the POST request, i am doing this and getting below responses:

```
Message in = exchange.getIn();
in.getBody(String.class); // print the error code 400
HttpServletRequest request = in.getBody(HttpServletRequest.class)// This is null.
```

Anything i am doing wrong? Do i need to set the message Content to the body of my Post Request?

Comment: A 400 means bad request. So it means either your request message or your URI is wrong. Does the server logs show that your request was sent and it looks correct? What about the headers that the server receives?

Comment: I cannot access the server logs. As i mentioned, the request object i get from exchange.in is null.

Comment: That is the reponse from the server, if you mean the 400 bad request? The easiest is probably to setup your own local server and test that first. That way you can see exactly what headers you are receiving and how the body looks before doing an integration test. Here is a simple server to play with http://tinyserver.sourceforge.net/

Comment: wow.. Never thought about that.. will try this out..

Comment: check class HttpProducer.

Comment: Did you mean producerTemplate class?

Comment: For the reference i was able to solve the issue. The problem was with the headers. JMS message was adding a whole lot of headers, and this caused the post request to fail. Removing all the headers solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be `String.class`:

```
in.getBody(String.class);
```

First check the type of server response, then try to print or log exchange body.

It should be `HttpServletResponse`:

```
HttpServletRequest request = in.getBody(HttpServletRequest.class)
```

Comment: It can be of string type. Do check this. http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html . I am able to print the response by converting it to String.

Comment: Also for the second part, this stackoverflow question points how to use httprequest object.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976812/how-to-dump-http-body-and-headers-sent-with-http-component-with-apache-camel